# onbeforeunload event is not getting bound in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, onbeforeunload

My jQuery code is working fine in IE and Chrome but not working in Firefox. The code is about asking for confirmation when a user exits the browser. Firefox is not binding the `onbeforeunload` event. It is asking for confirmation in IE and Chrome but not in Firefox.

Please help me. The code is as follows :

```js
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

j$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(window).bind("onbeforeunload", function() {
    return confirm("do you want to exit?", "true");
  });

  jQuery('a').on('click', function() {
    jQuery(window).unbind('onbeforeunload')
  });

  jQuery(window).bind('keydown keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 116) {
      jQuery(window).unbind('onbeforeunload');
    }
    if (e.which === 82 && e.ctrlKey) {
      jQuery(window).unbind('onbeforeunload');
    }
  });

  jQuery(window).mousedown(function(e) {
    if (e.button == 2) {
      jQuery(window).unbind('onbeforeunload');
    } else {
      jQuery(window).bind('onbeforeunload');
    }
  });

  jQuery("form").submit(function() {
    jQuery(window).unbind('onbeforeunload')
  });
});
```

Comment: Try `jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload'..`. Might also be because you have to either return true or false (or a string), not a function.

Comment: Thank you....I have tried this but it didn't work. Please suggest another solution

Comment: which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Sir, I am using v1.11.2

Comment: I copied your code into my sample test bug page, added a form element, submit button, a link. Loaded the page into Google Chrome. Tried to leave it and no confirm was present. Are you sure it is working in Chrome? If yes, then, please, provide some sample page, jsfiddle or any other more elaborate example

Comment: Sir, you can test the code with this link :

http://goo.gl/g23MJJ

and to download the code try this link :

http://goo.gl/CZ4SVW

Comment: have you fixed it already? it works in my FF

Comment: also you should use the `beforeunload` event, without any prefixes like `on` etc. They are being used only as html-tag attributes

Comment: Thanks Sir, it is fixed now